# .NET MAUI error No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

Occurs when binding my view to the view model.

Error description:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for type 'yournamespace.view.pagename'.'
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It turns out I just forgot to register the View and the ViewModel into MauiProgram.cs

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: @Asmtony, Add `builder.Services.AddSingleton<PageType>` in  `MauiProgram.cs`

Comment: Same mistake at my end.